# Ubuntu 15.10 won't boot for no evident reason

Tags: boot, crash

I was using Ubuntu 15.10 for a couple of weeks and then took a break for about a month. By the time I took my break, Ubuntu was working and booting completely fine, with no errors.

Now, after the break, I need to continue developing the website on Ubuntu. But it won't boot at all. What I see when booting normally:

1. Typical Ubuntu loading screen with dots running
2. Black screen with console messages of different services initialization, etc. Everything on it says [OK] at the left. Then it comes to the certain point where it just stops, freezes and nothing happens. I've waited for about 15 minutes at this point, believe me, nothing will happen.

Before, when Ubuntu was working fine, nothing of the following happened:

- I haven't installed, removed or changed any new/old packages
- I haven't installed any updates proposed by default Ubuntu Update manager
- I haven't witnessed any messages/warnings about something being wrong

What I've tried to fix this:

- **Boot-Repair**. Recommended repair did nothing.
- **Reinstall option in Installation type from Ubuntu installation USB**. Actually, I have no "Reinstall" option. It just says "Install", clicking on which says it's going to install another Ubuntu alongside my current one.
- **Recovery mode**. I've tried disk check, check for broken packages, updating and upgrading via root. No results.
- **Switching lightdm to gdm (via editing /etc/X11/default-display-manager)**. Did nothing, put it back to "lightdm" as it was originally.

I will attach my [boot.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/shc291hy6wne2rz/boot.log?dl=0) to this question, maybe it will give you guys some clue. I'm truly desperate, it's the second time Ubuntu just crashes and to bring it back to life seems nearly impossible. I cannot reinstall Ubuntu over and over in situations like these, it takes some time to configure it back after each reinstallation.

I really hope you can help me out. Thank you.

**NOTE:** The issue solved itself without me doing something. However, I would like to keep this question open to be safe in the future. Since it appeared with no background, it may appear again. I would like to know what to do in this sort of situations.

Comment: This question is about a version of Ubuntu that is [no longer supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), AskUbuntu doesn't accept questions about EOL (end of life) distributions

Comment: Sorry, I've mistyped the version of the system. It's a stable latest 15.10 (I guess).

Comment: Can you use `tty1`?

Comment: I can use `tty1`. It asks me of my usual login and password there, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you go into recovery mode then to the root command prompt and type

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

then

```
vi /etc/default/grub
```

Look for a line that  says

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=
```

Change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"
```

Save the file and run

```
update-grub
```

Now when you boot it will boot to the command prompt login.

Once logged in it should be running ...

you can try `startx`  and see if it locks up again. If it locks then you can look into your video drivers but at this point I don't have enough information to go by .. maybe when it comes to that point  someone else can suggest something...

setting it up the way I suggest will at least let you boot into your normal Ubuntu (though without a GUI) so you can easily edit it without having to use the recovery mode. Once you figure out the issue and fix it and `startx` boots you into GUI without an issue you can re-edit `/etc/default/grub` comment out that line we changed and do `sudo update-grub` and it will boot back into the GUI at bootime

Comment: Just wanted to try your suggestion when Ubuntu booted normally. I've just booted in in recovery mode and it started up fine. The most random boot issue I've ever encountered.

Comment: well good to hear its working again